Strapi Custom Plugin API Returning 404
I am trying to build a custom plugin, and everything works fine. I have created an API route in the plugin.
When testing locally (using resolve in plugin.js) in Strapi v5, everything works as expected, and the API functions properly. However, after publishing the plugin to npm and downloading it for use in Strapi v4, I am encountering a 404 error when calling the API in plugin.
Route.js file:
export default {
  config: {
    enabled: true,
    auth: false,
  },
  routes: [
    {
      method: 'ALL',
      path: '/get-configs',
      handler: 'myController.configs',
      config: {
        auth: false,
      },
    },
  ],
};


myController.js file

'use strict';

module.exports = ({ strapi }) => ({
  index(ctx) {
    ctx.body = strapi.plugin('random-content-filler').service('myService').getWelcomeMessage();
  },

  configs(ctx) {
    console.log('called configs');
    ctx.body = strapi.plugin('random-content-filler').service('myService').getConfigs();
  },
});

myService.js file
'use strict';

module.exports = ({ strapi }) => ({
  getWelcomeMessage() {
    return 'Welcome to Strapi ';
  },

  getConfigs() {
    return strapi.config.get('plugin.random-content-filler');
  },
});

Server file after build
const bootstrap = ({ strapi }) => {
};
const destroy = ({ strapi }) => {
};
const register = ({ strapi }) => {
};
const config = {
  default: {},
  validator() {
  }
};
const contentTypes = {};
const controller = ({ strapi }) => ({
  index(ctx) {
    ctx.body = strapi.plugin("random-content-filler").service("service").getWelcomeMessage();
  }
});
function getDefaultExportFromCjs(x) {
  return x && x.__esModule && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, "default") ? x["default"] : x;
}
var myController = ({ strapi }) => ({
  index(ctx) {
    ctx.body = strapi.plugin("random-content-filler").service("myService").getWelcomeMessage();
  },
  configs(ctx) {
    console.log("called configs");
    ctx.body = strapi.plugin("random-content-filler").service("myService").getConfigs();
  }
});
const myController$1 = /* @__PURE__ */ getDefaultExportFromCjs(myController);
const controllers = {
  controller,
  myController: myController$1
};
const middlewares = {};
const policies = {};
const routes = {
  config: {
    enabled: true,
    auth: false
  },
  routes: [
    {
      method: "GET",
      path: "/get-configs",
      handler: "myController.configs",
      config: {
        auth: false
      }
    }
  ]
};
const service = ({ strapi }) => ({
  getWelcomeMessage() {
    return "Welcome to Strapi ";
  }
});
var myService = ({ strapi }) => ({
  getWelcomeMessage() {
    return "Welcome to Strapi ";
  },
  getConfigs() {
    return strapi.config.get("plugin.random-content-filler");
  }
});
const myService$1 = /* @__PURE__ */ getDefaultExportFromCjs(myService);
const services = {
  service,
  myService: myService$1
};
const index = {
  register,
  bootstrap,
  destroy,
  config,
  controllers,
  routes,
  services,
  contentTypes,
  policies,
  middlewares
};
export {
  index as default
};

